# Emulate Repeating Section form behavior in Word 2007/2010

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2007

I have created a form in Word 2013 which has several blocks used to input user data.  Each of these blocks correspond to one type of item, and each block is surrounded by a repeating section form to allow the user to enter multiple items of that type.

When loading this form in Word 2007/2010, all of the forms function fine, with the exception of the repeating section form.  It does not appear that this functionality existed in in the older version as there is no "legacy form" option available in Word 2013.

How can I emulate the desired behavior in old versions of Word?